# How can I display data in a RecyclerView within a fragment?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Can you help me? I have an issue when displaying data from the server using RecyclerView in my fragment. The problem is that the RecyclerView is not visible when the program is run, but when I use a text view to display data from the response, the program runs fine.

This My Fragment:
HomeActivity.kt

```
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response: Response<GetAllPost> = apiService.getAllPost("Bearer $token")
                recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val getAllPost: GetAllPost? = response.body()
                    Log.d("YourFragment", "Response: ${getAllPost?.toString()}")
                    getAllPost?.let {
                        val dataItems: List<DataItem> = it.data?.filterNotNull() ?: emptyList()
                        if (dataItems.isNotEmpty()) {
//                            Log.d("YourFragment", "Data Size: ${dataItems.size}")
//                            val firstDataItem = dataItems[0] // Ambil item pertama dari dataItems
//                            val textToDisplay = "Teks yang ingin Anda tampilkan: ${firstDataItem.judulPost}" // Sesuaikan dengan field yang ingin ditampilkan
//                            val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView4) // Ganti dengan ID TextView yang Anda miliki
//                            textView.text = textToDisplay // Set teks ke TextView
//                        } else {
//                            val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView4) // Ganti dengan ID TextView yang Anda miliki
//                            textView.text = "Tidak ada data" // Atur teks jika dataItems kosong
//
                         //Inisialisasi adapter dengan data dari response
                        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
                        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                        val adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(dataItems)
                        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        }



                    }
```

This My Adapter:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val dataItems: List<DataItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.arraylist, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val dataItem = dataItems[position]
        holder.txtJudulPost.text = "Judul Post: ${dataItem.judulPost}"
        holder.txtDeskripsi.text = "Deskripsi: ${dataItem.deskripsi}"
        holder.txtTanggalPost.text = "Tanggal Post: ${dataItem.tanggalPost}"
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataItems.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val txtJudulPost: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtJudulPost)
        val txtDeskripsi: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDeskripsi)
        val txtTanggalPost: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTanggalPost)
    }
}
```

this my data class response
data class DataItem(

```
@SerializedName("listReply")
    val listReply: List<Any?>? = null,

    @SerializedName("fotoKonten")
    val fotoKonten: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("tanggalPost")
    val tanggalPost: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("deskripsi")
    val deskripsi: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("judulPost")
    val judulPost: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("upvote")
    val upvote: Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("user")
    val user: User? = null,

    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("idPost")
    val idPost: Int? = null
)
```

and here is a screenshot of my program running and debugging
[image]

and here is a screenshot of my program running with textview
[image]

Seriously, this is making me dizzy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: im sorry i newbie in stack overflow

Comment: That's fine. Simply rework your question as this is far too much right now

Comment: I want to display my data in a RecyclerView, but the RecyclerView is not showing. I tried displaying the data using textviews, and the data appears. Is there something wrong with my adapter?

Comment: Can you add your .XML ?